# Why isn't there a deep copy method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, copy, deep-copy

I am working on a solution for technical drawings (svg/ruby). I want to manipulate rectangles, and have an `add!` method in this class:

```
class Rect
  def add!(delta)
    @x1+=delta 
    ... # and so on
    self
  end
end
```

I also need an `add` method returning a `Rect`, but not manipulating `self`:

```
def add(delta)
  r=self.dup/clone/"copy" # <-- not realy the 3 and no quotes, just in text here
  r.add! delta
end
```

`dup` and `clone` don't do my thing but:

```
def copy; Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(self)); end
```

does.

Why does such a basic functionality not exist in plain Ruby? Please just don't tell me that I could reverse `add` and `add!`, letting `add` do the job, and `add!` calling it.

Comment: Why it doesn't exist? It does: `Marshal.dump` + `Marshal.load`. Can you name some of programming languages that have deep copy on the language level?

Comment: your point, I think, that I am like a spoiled child with Ruby, finding all here, that I missed on other places :-D

Comment: “Why” makes this question hard/impossible for anyone other than Matz, et al., to answer.

Comment: got it, I think you talk about the title of the question, I correct that

Comment: Have you seen this Ruby gem? https://github.com/balmma/ruby-deepclone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why there's no deep copy method in Ruby, but I'll try to make an educated guess based on the information I could find (see links and quotes below the line).

Judging from this information, I could only infer that the reason Ruby does not have a deep copy method is because it's very rarely necessary and, in the few cases where it truly is necessary, there are other, relatively simple ways to accomplish the same task:

As you already know, using `Marshal.dump` and `Marshal.load` is currently the recommended way to do this. This is also the approach recommended by Programming Ruby (see excerpts below).

Alternatively, there are at least 3 available implementations found in these gems: [`deep_cloneable`](http://rubygems.org/gems/deep_cloneable), [`deep_clone`](http://rubygems.org/gems/deep_clone) and [`ruby_deep_clone`](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_deep_clone); the first being the most popular.

---

**Related Information**

Here's [a discussion over at comp.lang.ruby](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.ruby/iiQialTnnSQ) which might shed some light on this. There's [another answer here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.ruby/VQXB5mJC4lU/EVb7omQ5jj0J) with some associated discussions, but it all comes back to using `Marshal`.

There weren't any mentions of deep copying in [Programming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0), but there were a few mentions in [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0026OR3JO). Here are a few related excerpts:

> […]
>
> Another use for `Marshal.dump` and `Marshal.load` is to create deep copies
>   of objects:
>
> ```
> def deepcopy(o)
>   Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(o))
> end
> ```
>
> […]
>
> … the binary format used by `Marshal.dump` and `Marshal.load` is
>   version-dependent, and newer versions of Ruby are not guaranteed to be
>   able to read marshalled objects written by older versions of Ruby.
>
> […]
>
> Note that files and I/O streams, as well as Method and Binding
>   objects, are too dynamic to be marshalled; there would be no reliable
>   way to restore their state.
>
> […]
>
> Instead of making a defensive deep copy of the array, just call
>   `to_enum` on it, and pass the resulting enumerator instead of the array
>   itself. In effect, you’re creating an enumerable but immutable proxy
>   object for your array.

Comment: this is more than an answer; my conclusion - taking your links in concern - is, that (deep)copying an object is (more or less often) a pointer for a bad design.

Comment: Regarding the last point regarding using to_enum. I tried this but its not working as expected. 
I am using Ruby 2.2.0
a = [1,2,3,4]     => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
b = a.to_enum => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:each> 
a << 5              => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
b                      => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:each> 

How is creating enumerable create an immutable poxy object for the array ?.

Answer (score 2):

Forget marshalling. The deep_dive gem will solve your problems.

https://rubygems.org/gems/deep_dive

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use something like this:

```
new_item = Item.new(old_item.attributes)
new_item.save!
```

This would copy all the attributes from existing item to new one, without issues. If you have other objects, you can just copy them individually.

I think it's the quickest way to copy an object

Comment: If you are dealing with ActiveRecord type objects, that would work, perhaps. But that obviously would not work for any Ruby object.