# Ruby Array assignments updating when its not supposed to

Tags: ruby, arrays, sudoku

Basically I'm making a program that can solve a sudoku puzzle for me, and I want to maintain a start point of the original input matrix to have to option to reset the board and start again, if the program gets stuck in a rabbit hole.  I want to store my original in a field variable called @start, and have it never be touched in the course of the algorithm.

Is there some kind of keyword that I must use?  I've tried .map, I've tried manually copying it from the input matrix.

```
class Game
def initialize(gamematrix)
  @start=gamematrix
  @rows=gamematrix
    puts "rows - #{@rows}"
  @cols=@rows.transpose
end

def findnils
puts "finding the nils"
sleep 0.1

     nilspaces=[]
    g=0
    while g<@cols.length
puts "3  we parse through col #{g}"
sleep 0.1
      p=0
        while p<@rows.length
if @rows[g][p]!=nil
  puts "4 [#{g}][#{p}]"
end
sleep 0.1
          if @rows[g][p]==nil
           puts "      [#{g}][#{p}] :found a nil!!!"
              nilspaces<<[g,p]
          end
        p+=1
        end
      g+=1
    end
    return nilspaces

end

def sudku
puts '1  we\'re in the sudku method'
#sleep 0.8
    #update the coordinatebank of nill spaces in the matric
#sleep 0.8
 nilspaces=findnils

  while !win?
  puts '5 now our nilspaces array now looks like this: '
  puts "nils: [#{nilspaces}]"
  sleep 0.4

      #randomly find an empty nil space, find its coordinates in the matrix
    current=nilspaces.sample
  puts "out current nilspace is [#{current}]"
  sleep 0.2
      nilspaces.delete_if{|e| e==current}
  puts "nils: [#{nilspaces}]"
  sleep 0.2
      #then use the guessNum method to guess based on the coordinates
      guessedN=guessNum(@cols[current[0]], @rows[current[1]])
  puts "guessed: #{guessedN}"
  sleep 0.2
      #assign out guessed number to replace the nil
      if guessedN != 999
        @rows[current[0]][current[1]]=guessedN
  sleep 0.1
  puts "guessed rturns a number so @rows is #{@rows[current[0]][current[1]]}"
  puts "          start matrix: #{@start}"

      else
        puts "=========================="
        #reset
          puts "resets everything"
            sleep 0.3
            @rows=@start
            @cols=@rows.transpose
          puts "rows: #{@rows}"
          puts "cols: #{@cols}"
        nilspaces=findnils
        puts "=========================="
        sleep 0.1
      end

      display
    sleep 0.4

  end

end



def guessNum(vset, hset)
                          #create an array of numbers to choose from
choice=(1..@rows.length).to_a
                          #subtract everything in the choice array thats in the hset
choice.delete_if {|e| hset.include?(e)}
                          #subtract everything in the choice array thats in the vset
choice.delete_if {|e| vset.include?(e)}
                          #if nothing is left in the choice array return a string called empty
                          #otherwise return a random number from the array (the choice array)
    if choice.empty?
      return 999
    else
      return choice.sample
    end

end

def display
  puts "--------------------"
  for g in @rows
    out="        "
    for l in g
      out+= "#{'%03s' % l.to_s}"
    end
    out+=" \n"
    puts out
  end
  puts "--------------------"
end


def win?
[@rows.all? { |e| e.uniq.length==@rows.length }, @cols.all? { |e| e.uniq.length==@cols.length }].all? { |e| e==true  }
end

end
```

The driver test is this:

easygame4x4=[[4,nil,nil,nil],[nil,3,4,nil],[nil,1,2,nil],[nil,nil,nil,1]]

gameone=Game.new(easygame4x4)

gameone.sudku

you can run this and see how it works, I put a bunch of puts statements and sleep statements in this to walk anyone through the process, the problem is, my @start matrix always get updated with the @rows matrix

Comment: Should help: https://github.com/dkubb/adamantium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:  its a matrix input, so i have to .map it twice to really clone it.

Answer (score 2):

Use Ruby methods [`clone`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-clone), [`freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-freeze), and [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup)

Example:

```
def initialize(gamematrix)
  @start=gamematrix.clone.freeze
```

When you do `anything = @start` do it like this:

```
@rows=@start.dup
```

What you're seeing in your code is Ruby modifying an object:

```
array1 = ["a"]
array2 = array1  # now these variables point to the same place
array2[0] #=> "a" as you expect
array1[0] = "b"
array2[0] #=> "b" because array1 and array2 point to the same place
```

What clone does is make a shallow copy, a.k.a. shallow clone:

```
array1 = ["a"]
array2 = array1.clone # now array2 points to a new place
array2[0] #=> "a" as you expect
array1[0] = "b"
array2 #=> ["a"] because array2 points to its own place, not array1's place
```

The difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy:

```
array1 = [["a"]]
array2 = array1.clone # array2 points to a new place, which in turn points to the array that contains "a"
array1[0][0] = "b"  # you're changing the array that contains "a"
array2 #=> [["b"]]  # because array2 points to its own place, which in turn still points to the same array that contained "a"
```

What you need for you code is a deep copy, a.k.a. deep clone. Ruby doesn't have this method (which is an error IMHO) so the typical solution is to use a gem, or the Ruby `Marshall` methods. See
[Why isn't there a deep copy method in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912476/why-isnt-there-a-deep-copy-method-in-ruby)

What dup does is like clone except dup doesn't copy the frozen state:

```
s = "foo"
s.clone.frozen?  # true
s.dup.frozen?  # false
```

Your particular application is modifying the rows, so that's why your reset functionality should use `dup` instead of `clone`.

If you're writing your own object class for you matrix, then you may need to write your own `clone` method, such as:

```
class GameMatrix

  def clone
    # create a clone as you want,
    # such as initializing a new object,
    # and/or cloning sub-objects, etc.,
    # including singleton/class methods,
    # including frozen state, etc.
  end

  def dup
    # create a duplicate as you want,
    # such as initializing a new object,
    # and/or duplicating sub-objects, but
    # excluding singleton/class methods,
    # excluding frozen state, etc.
  end

end
```

Extra notes...

The `clone` and `dup` methods are up to each class to define, so read the documentation for each. In general, `clone` is a superset of dup, because `clone` also copies singleton methods, frozen state, and more.

The `freeze` method isn't really necessary and it behaves unexpected (IMHO) yet it's still worth using the method because it helps a bit, and shows your other code readers that you intend the object to be constant.

Comment: still not preserving it,  is there somewhere in the code that i'm manipulating @star that I can't see?

Comment: Are you also doing a `clone` when resetting? i.e. `@rows=@start.clone`

Comment: I tried that just now and it still didn't work,  i added a method to test if my start variables can be preserved and it worked, there s just something in that sudoku method thats triggering it to update it with rows but i just can't spot it.  Could there be a glitch in ruby? 
       def original
          for g in (1..4)
            puts "rows  #{rows.map { |e| e.map { |f|  g } }}"
            puts "start #{start}"
           end
        end
This yielded results that would be expected.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson  thank you!  https://github.com/laomatt/rubyexcercises/blob/master/sudoku3.rb

Comment: ok, I stripped it down to the bare bones of whats not working, you can see it here https://github.com/laomatt/experimentalruby/blob/master/sudoku4.rb  apparently its my guessNum method that makes it update for some reason, because when i do other things to the rows array it doesn't affect the start array  @joelparkerhenderson

Comment: Updated with a solution for you.